# какие однородные в этом предложении?

Tags: однородные-члены

> Вот неделя, другая проходит.

Как правильно сформулировать, чем осложнено предложение? Здесь однородные подлежащие/определения?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Вот неделя, другая проходит*.
> Чем осложнено это предложение?

Предложение осложнено **однородными подлежащими**.

Во втором подлежащем (***другая неделя***) опущено слово ***неделя***.